# Abstract Elements and Types over SOAP in .net?

Tags: .net, wcf, class, abstract

I have a WSDL file which has xsd part in it which has abstract elements and types in it. When C#.net web forms project creates proxy classes for consuming web service after adding web reference to previously mentioned WSDL, it replaces every abstract class with a concrete one. Why is that? Is it generally wrong to use abstract types in WSDL for web services?

Answer (score 0):

When the client builds the web service references, it reads messages and it builds the proxy class from the messages. Messages contain serializable DTOs not the original objects. DTOs are data which are a representation of the original objects. Abstract object oriented concept has nothing to do with DTOs transmitted through a web service.
Huge discussion on this topic there:
[WHY doesn't WCF 'properly' consume/expose abstract types when hosted as a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839696/why-doesnt-wcf-properly-consume-expose-abstract-types-when-hosted-as-a-web-se)